# MongoDB Aggregation pipeline: use of For loop

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am wondering whether someone has better way of querying in MongoDB.

I have a collection where it stores hourly information for a userid. This Collection will have each document for a unique user_id and date combination. But user_id can have multiple entires with different dates. Sample document entries are given below

```
{ user_id : A,
  date.   : '2020-04-01'
 hourly_info : 
   { metric_one :
        { 0 : 4, 
          1: 7,
          2:8
          ..
          23: 43 }}}
```

My problem is : for a given user_id and daterange, group by user_id, and calculate sum of metric_one for each hour. sample output would look like below

{ "_id" : "A", "0" : 45, "1" : 28, "2" : 31, .... "23": 67}.

My query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      { '$match': {
           'user_id':"A",   
           'date':{'$lte':ISODate('2020-04-01'),     
           '$gte':ISODate('2020-04-08')   } 
      } }, 
      {'$group':{
            _id: '$user_id', 
           '0': { '$sum': '$hourly_info.metric_one.0'}, 
           '1': { '$sum': '$hourly_info.metric_one.1'}, 
           ... ,
           '23':{ '$sum': '$hourly_info.metric_one.23'}
      }}
]).pretty()
```

I would really appreciate if someone could say if there any better way of querying other than summing for each and every hour from 0 to 23.

Is there better way that i can make use for loop so that i don't to have write same summing logic for 0 to 23?

something like below

```
for (i = 0; i <= 23; i=i+1){ 
db.collection.aggregate([{
    '$match': {
      'user_id':"A",
      'sales_date':{
        '$lte':ISODate('2020-04-01'),
        '$gte':ISODate('2020-04-08')
      }
    }
}, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$user_id',
            {i}: {
                '$sum': '$hourly_info.metric_one.{i}'
            }
        }
     }
])
```

}

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with aggregation.  You can use $objectToArray and unwind to split the hourly data into separate documents, then group twice - once to count each hour, and once to collect that together for the user.  Then $arrayToObject to make it an object again.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {'$match': {
           'user_id':"A",   
           'date':{'$gte':ISODate('2020-04-01'),     
                   '$lte':ISODate('2020-04-08')} 
      }}, 
      {'$addFields':{
           'hourly_info.metric_one': {$objectToArray: '$hourly_info.metric_one'}
      }},
      {'$unwind':'$hourly_info.metric_one'},
      {'$group':{
            _id: {
                  'user':'$user_id',
                  'hour':'$hourly_info.metric_one.k'
            },
           'total': { '$sum': '$hourly_info.metric_one.v'}
      }},
      {'$group':{
           '_id':'$_id.user',
           'hourly':{'$push':{'k':'$_id.hour','v':'$total'}}
      }},
      {'$addFields': {'hourly':{'$arrayToObject':'$hourly'}}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T47oFAxjFqR)

Comment: Thank you so much :) it helped!  
However, i have a question, this involves creating an array, unwinding it and grouping by operation. if we have to perform this aggregation over huge number of documents, let's say for 2 or 3 years for a user_id,  is this method is efficient as summing up individually  approach ( as mentioned in my problem approach). Wondering which way to go in that case? ( even though the code is ugly in old approach, which would be computationally efficient?)