# How to convert structure of mongo db document's object

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a document with the following structure:

```
id:  6229d3fd40bac327243e4ww2
userID: "594e710c-c632-3ae-929a-f13e294ee6ef"
appID: "622994e2b98225609b89affd"
notifications:Object
     6229d3e040bac3272qwe4441: 1  
     622ew3e041bac3272qwe4441: 1
```

I want to update this structure to this:

```
id:  6229d3fd40bac327243e4ww2
userID: "594e710c-c632-43ae-929a-f13e294ee6ef"
appID: "622994e2b98225609b89affd"
notifications:Object
     6229d3e040bac3272qwe4441: {a:1, b:false}  
     622ew3e040bac3272qwe4441: {a:1, b:false}
```

I am having trouble with iterating the `notification` objects fields as its is random hex string.
I have tried using following solutions but not able to get the expected result
[MongoDB Aggregation pipeline: use of For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219272/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-use-of-for-loop)

Comment: why use an object with random hex strings?  Could this not be accomplished with an array of objects instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      notifications: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$notifications" },
            as: "n",
            in: {
              k: "$$n.k",
              v: { a: "$$n.v", b: false }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sBgo_Ov6KRo)